# Why is my HTML Value not Found when the ID is correct?

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, automation

I am trying to enter a value into a search box via my works private intranet website, but it cannot seem to find the ID of the box. When I select the element, it tells me that it is not found. Here is the source code:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim z As HTMLDocument
Dim menuSelect As Object
Dim actID As String
Dim UGV As Object
Dim wName As String

wName = "test name"


Set i = New InternetExplorerMedium

With i
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "xxxxx"
    While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy: DoEvents: Wend
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Set z = i.document
End With

With z
    .getElementById("RAD_SLIDING_PANE_TEXT_RadSlidingPane1").Click
    
    Set menuSelect = .getElementsByClassName("rmText")
    
    For x = 0 To menuSelect.Length - 1
        If menuSelect(x).innerText = "Utils: View Users" Then
            menuSelect(x).Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    
    .getElementById("txtSearch").Value = wName //<------ Error 91 "Object variable or with block not set" points to this line
    .getElementById("btnSearch").Click
    
    Set UGV = .getElementsByClassName("TableItem")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")
    
    For x = 0 To UGV.Length - 1
        If UGV(x).innerText = wName Then
            actID = UGV(x).innerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    MsgBox actID
End With

End Sub
```

I have also tried .getelementsbyName and looping through all the input tags to automatically determine the name/ID, but it cannot find any values underneath

```
<IFRAME name=iFrm_Right width="100%" height="100%" id=iFrm_Right src="about:blank" frameBorder=0 style="DISPLAY: block"></IFRAME>
```

at the very top

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please remove the javascript tag, as you are not using javascript

Comment: Are you searching the `document` object within the   `#IFrm_Right` frame element and not the web page's `document` element. See [HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) or [HTMLIFrameElement.contentDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) for more details. Bear in mind security imposed by `src="about:blank"` may prevent access. Sorry I can't answer in vba terms.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're accessing an element in an iframe. The way to access elements in iframes is different from the normal one.

I don't know why the `src` of the iframe is `about:blank`. But if the element is in the iframe which id is `iFrm_Right`, you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#finding_the_first_element_matching_a_class) method to get the Iframe through id, then according to the `Iframe.contentDocument` property to reach the element via the id:

```
With z
    ...
    .querySelector("#iFrm_Right").contentDocument.getElementById("txtSearch").Value = wName
```